# How to install Visual Studio Code on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have just downloaded VSCode-linux-x64 from the [Microsoft website](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download). It's a zip file called VSCode-linux-x64.zip. How can I install it on my Linux system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and posting the answer so it can help others.
To download and install Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu . follow the steps below

- [Download Visual Studio Code for Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download)
- Extract the zip file `VSCode-linux-x64.zip`
- Go inside the folder `VSCode-linux-x64`
- double click and Run `code` executable to open Visual Studio Code .
- You can right click on Visual Studio Code on toolbar (or launcher)
  and select Lock to Launcher. this way you can launch the editor by
  clicking it on launcher.

If you are using terminal follow the terminal commands

- `mkdir your_folder_name && cd your_folder_name  unzip`
- `../Downloads/VSCode-linux-x64.zip`
- `./Code`

[This video](https://youtu.be/uYE0XrM-VZA) will help you to download and install and use Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu if you still have some doubts

Answer (score 5):

From a few pages deeper into the [setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup#_linux) docs in the link you offered...

> Linux
>
> 1. Download Visual Studio Code for Linux
> 2. Make a new folder and extract `VSCode-linux-x64.zip` inside that folder
> 3. Double click on `Code` to run Visual Studio Code
>
> Tip: If you want to run VSCode from the terminal, create the following
>   link substituting `/path/to/vscode/Code` with the absolute path to the
>   `Code` executable
>   `sudo ln -s /path/to/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin/code` in any folder to start editing files in that
>   folder.
>
> Now, you can simply type `code .` in any folder to start editing files
>   in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

After `18.04` version, the following one-line terminal code works well.

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```

Answer (score 1):

**Installing with apt-get:**

Step 1 – Enable Package Repository

Run the following command to enable Visual studio code repository to your system:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" | sudo \ tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vs-code.list
```

Step 2 – Install Visual Studio Code Editor

Now, Import the package signing gpg key on your system using the following command:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
```

Install Visual Studio Code on your Debian based system (like Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install code
```

Step 3 – Launch Visual Studio Code and enable its extensions:

Now You can launch the Visual Studio Code editor on your system using the graphical menu.

[image]

There are a large number of extensions available for Visual Studio Code like PHP, Python, JavaScript etc. Install the required extensions to enhance your working experience with Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Source: https://tecadmin.net/install-visual-studio-code-editor-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

For **Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS)** by terminal

1. Update the system

> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

2. Install packages

> sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget -y

3. Import repository

> wget -O- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/vscode.gpg

> echo deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/vscode.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list

4. Update the system again

> sudo  apt update

5. Install the VS-Code

> **sudo apt install code**

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way to install Visual Studio Code in Linux
I hope it useful.
Installing Visual Studio Code in Kali Linux - 4 simple steps

1. Update your system and install the below package.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install curl gpg software-properties-common apt-transport-https
   ```
2. Importing Microsoft GPG key to Kali Linux

   ```
   curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Adding APT repository for VS Code to Kali Linux

   ```
    echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
   ```
4. Installing VS Code

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install code
   ```

For reference:
https://youtu.be/ycIjQf0rOJI

Comment: Not my downvotes, but this basically duplicates the earlier answer for Debian-based systems like Ubuntu, Mint, etc. There is noting specific to Kali Linux here (but if you are using Kali as a general-purpose system, you are doing something very wrong).